# C# MVC HTML5 file upload control with multiple attribute duplicates images

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

I am having a strange issue with HTML5 file upload control with `multiple` attribute. I have no clue about how to fix it. I am trying to explain the problem below:

When uploading multiple images on the server, the images are uploading but some of them are getting duplicated, not by name, but by image itself.

Means if I select say 10 images, I can see 10 images are uploaded with different names (names are generated dynamically) but say 4 images are exactly the same. Means, 6 out of 10 selected images uploaded perfectly, but 4 original images got disappeared completely! But these 4 images are using contents from 6 images uploaded correctly. Moreover, this is happening in random. There is no order or sequence from what I can understand what will disappear and what will re-uploaded with a different name.

**In short:**

- Selected 10 different images for upload
- Number of images uploaded is 10
- 6 images (say) uploaded with correct content
- 4 images (say) uploaded with correct file name, but content is wrong. They are using contents of 6 images and original content of these images simply disappeared.

This is happening when I am selecting more than 5 images for upload. Anything less than 6 has no problem.

Now when I test the same code at local development environment this is not happening at all! I checked folder permission on the server and there is no restriction imposed.

I am not sure whether I could explain the issue correctly because it is really a typical one and I never encountered similar thing before !!

**Markup:**

```
<div class="row gapp-10 medium">
     <div class="col-md-9">
         Upload Photos <span class="small-font gray-text">(Optional)</span> <span class="small-font red-text">
        (Combined upload size can't exceed 10mb.)</span>
        <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VehicleImages, new {@type="file", @id="fUpload", @multiple="multiple", @class="btn btn-clc-theme-orange"}) %>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller Action method:**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(VehicleViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     _service = new VehicleService();
     model.SellerId = CommonMethods.LoggedInUser.SellerId;
     var newVehicle = _service.Save(model);
     newVehicleId = newVehicle.VehilceId;

     for (var i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
     {
        var fl = Request.Files[i];
        if (fl == null || fl.ContentLength <= 0) continue;
        var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fl.FileName.Trim());
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)) continue;

        var fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);
        var newFileName = String.Concat(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), fileExtension);
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/VehiclePhoto/" + newVehicleId));
        var photoPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/VehiclePhoto/" + newVehicleId + "/"), newFileName);

        fl.SaveAs(photoPath);
     }
   }

   return RedirectToAction("VehicleUploaded");
}
```

### Edit

This is how the upload control is placed inside the form element and the method is being called. Nothing fancy, just the simple and classical way.

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Upload", "VehicleUpload", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{ %>
    ...
    <div class="row gapp-10 medium">
       <div class="col-md-9">
          Upload Photos <span class="small-font gray-text">(Optional)</span>
          <span class="small-font red-text">(Combined upload size can't exceed 10mb.)</span>
          <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VehicleImages, new {@type="file", @id="fUpload", @multiple="multiple", @class="btn btn-clc-theme-orange"}) %>
       </div>
       <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Vehicle" class="btn btn-primary" />
<% } %>
```

Comment: I don't know which plugin/method you're using to reach the controller method, are you mean remaining 4 images turned into duplicated image content but with different naming than original one?

Comment: There is no plugin or anything. Its just a pure ASPX based view page with a file uploader control. The controller method is being reached normally, i.e. just by using HTML form control only by the help of Controller name and Method name. There is no AJAX or anything else working in between.      Now, to answer your question, yes. This is exactly what is happening. However, 4 is just an example, this could be 5, 2, 1, 6.. anything. It is completely random and I could not figure out any proper pattern it is following while doing this.

Comment: I edited my question to show how and where the uploader control is placed and the form submission is happening.